# ¿Cómo puedo completar y no omitir una lista en caso de condicionar "if not in list"?

Tags: python

Tomemos como referencia la `lista1` que tiene 5 elementos en ella:

```
lista1 = ['pulpo', 'gato', 'perro', 'lobo', 'pez']
```

Con la `lista2` quiero crear aleatoriamente 5 números diferentes que se almacenen en la lista y reitero **que no se repitan**.

```
lista2 = []
for i in range(0, len(lista1)-1)
    numeros = randint(2, 6)
    if numeros not in lista2:
        lista2.append(numeros)
```

Tomando en cuenta la lista anterior, quiero igualmente completar en un rango muy pequeño una combinación pero, no quiero que se omita el número que falta por la condición.
Y completar en una nueva lista:

```
contador = 0
lista2 = []
animales = []
for i in range(0, len(lista1)-1)
    contador + = 1
    numeros = randint(2, 6)
    if numeros not in lista2:
        lista2.append(numeros)
animales.append(f'{lista1}{lista2[contador-1]}')
print(", ".join(animales))
```

De tal modo que imprima más o menos:

```
3pulpo, 5gato, 2perro, 6lobo, 4pez
```

Lo anterior, es el resultado que espero, pero en ocasiones me arroja esto **IndexError: list index out of range**. Debido a la omisión de la variable en la lista y como consecuencia, el rango se hace más pequeño.

Entonces, la pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo evitar que se omita en una lista, la variable iterada en caso de que la condicional `if not in lista` cumpla que no se repita?

De antemano agradezco mucho su ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problemas con el método**

```
for i in range(0, len(lista1)-1)
    numeros = randint(2, 6)
```

1. Error de sintaxis. Falta el ":" al final.
2. Si la lista tiene 5 elementos, este `for` sólo itera 4 veces. La forma correcta sería:

   for i in range(0, len(lista1)):
3. Aun cuando iteres la cantidad de veces necesaria, el `radint` puede entregar un valor repetido, y la lista final no tendrá el largo deseado.

**La forma pythonesca**

En Python se estila usar listas y sus métodos en lugar de ciclos iterativos.

El siguiente código produce el resultado pedido:

```
from random import shuffle

lista1 = ['pulpo', 'gato', 'perro', 'lobo', 'pez']
lista2 = [i for i in range(len(lista1))]
shuffle(lista2)
lista3 = [f"{lista2[i]}{lista1[i]}" for i in range(len(lista1))]

print(', '.join(lista3))
```

Para construir la lista de enteros desordenados sin repetición, primero generamos una lista ordenada usando una comprensión de listas

```
lista2 = [i for i in range(len(lista1))] => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Esa lista la desordenamos con el método `shuffle`.

Ahora tenemos dos listas, de igual largo que recorremos con otra comprensión de lista, creando el texto pedido a partir de elementos de ambas listas:

```
lista3 = [f"{lista2[i]}{lista1[i]}" for i in range(len(lista1))]
```

Esta lista la convertimos a un string usando `', '.join()`, que inserta una ", " entre cada valor.

#### Demo

```
from random import shuffle

lista1 = ['pulpo', 'gato', 'perro', 'lobo', 'pez']
lista2 = [i for i in range(len(lista1))]
shuffle(lista2)
lista3 = [f"{lista2[i]}{lista1[i]}" for i in range(len(lista1))]

print(', '.join(lista3))
```

produce:

```
2pulpo, 3gato, 1perro, 4lobo, 0pez

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Lo del error del punto lo puse mal aquí, pero al imprimirlo inmediatamente me lo hubiera marcado y sobre por qué puse `len(lista1)-1` es porque al definir la cantidad de números de la lista, este se cuenta desde el 0 y si son 5 elementos, me imprime 4. Por eso la longitud me arroja 5, pero tengo que quitarle -1. Tu respuesta me ha sido muy útil, muchas gracias @Candid Moe

Answer (score 1):

Solo añadir una forma alternativa, quizás un poco más "pythonesca" sería:

```
from random import sample

palabras = ['pulpo', 'gato', 'perro', 'lobo', 'pez']
numeros = sample(range(len(palabras)), len(palabras))
mix = [f"{numero}{palabra}" for numero, palabra in zip(numeros,palabras)]

print(', '.join(mix))
```

Usando `sample()` obtienes una cantidad arbitraria de "elementos" de una lista dada; sus argumentos serian `sample(lista_de_elementos, cuantos_elementos)`. De tal forma que le damos una lista con un numero por cada elemento de la lista de palabras con `range(len(palabras))` y cuantos elementos (todos) con `len(palabras)`.

Como ambas listas son igual de grandes (una se crea en base a la otra) se pueden recorrer en un for loop a la vez con `zip()` y desempaquetas al mismo tiempo el resultado con `numero, palabra` antes de `in zip(...)`

Al final el resultado es el mismo. Usa el que mejor entiendas.

También te sugiero que leas la documentación de `sample()` y `zip()`porque son funciones muy útiles.

Un saludo,

#### EDIT:

Releyendo tu pregunta puedo entender que no quieres números aleatorios entre 0 y el tamaño de tu lista; tiene fácil solución. Cambia `range(len(palabras))` en la función `sample()` por el rango de números que quieras y deja `len(palabras)` porque te seguirá dando una lista del mismo tamaño que la lista "palabras".

Por ejemplo:

```
sample(range(100), 5)

>>> [6, 46, 14, 47, 27]
```

...te devuelve una lista de 5 números entre 0 y 99. Si tienes una lista de palabras muy grande y solo quisieras algunas palabras al azar sin repetir, en lugar de darle `range()`, le das la lista entera y cuantas palabras quieres.